# JSON Web Token - Detach token from particular request

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm working on a multi-module Angular 7 project.

I have injected an interceptor in the root module , which is attaching a bearer token to every subsequent request and working fine. However, I'm trying to hit a `GET` request to third-party API for airport information, but the bearer token is getting attached with this request, because of which i'm getting this error:

```
http failure response
```

Is there any way to detach bearer token from API request?
[image]
[image]

Here is Interceptor code, I'm checking if a request is API link, if it is then  Authorization token is empty, eventhough is not working.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';


@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })

export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

constructor(private injector:Injector) { }
intercept(req, next){

let authservice = this.injector.get(AuthService);

 // check if request is API link,
 if(req.url == `https://airport-info.p.rapidapi.com/airport/?iata=${localStorage.getItem('iata')}`){
   let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
     setHeaders: {
      Authorization: 
    }
   })
   return next.handle(tokenizedReq)
 }
let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${authservice.getToken()}`
  }
})
  return next.handle(tokenizedReq)
 }
}
```

Comment: Probably there is a way to exclude it in the interceptor where you are including it. Show us your code so that we can help :)

Comment: @HristoEnev see my interceptor code

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  **excludedUrls property from your KeycloakOptions (better approach)** or **clearToken()** on that particular request.

Example using excludedUrls property (clearToken() option commented inside):

**keycloak-token.interceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class KeycloakTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

   ...

   constructor(private keycloak: KeycloakService) {}


   public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { 
       if (!this.keycloak.enableBearerInterceptor) {
           return next.handle(request);
       }

       const pass: boolean = this.keycloak.excludedUrls.findIndex(url => this.isUrlExcluded(request, url)) > -1;

       if (pass) {
           return next.handle(request);
       }

       // You can also try to use this.keycloak.clearToken() option here

       // If nothing from above happens it will just add the Token to the request
       return this.keycloak.addTokenToHeader(request.headers)
           .pipe(
               mergeMap(newHeaders => {
                   const keycloakRequest = request.clone({ headers: newHeaders });
                   return next.handle(keycloakRequest);
               }
           )
   }

   private isUrlExcluded({ method, url }: HttpRequest<any>, { urlPattern, httpMethods }: ExcludedUrlRegex): boolean {
        const httpTest = httpMethods.length === 0 || httpMethods.join().indexOf(method.toUpperCase()) > -1;
        const urlTest = urlPattern.test(url);
        return httpTest && urlTest;
    }

}
```

[More info here](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular)